# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'] with root cause

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, jndi

I am trying to establish a connection to the database using a jndi look up

this is my context.xml that I have defined in my webapp meta-inf folder

```
<Resource name="jdbc/connectDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="root"
        password="" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/connect" />
```

I am calling this in web.xml folder using this process

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/connectDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

After research to resolve the error, I have also tried referencing the file in my catalina folder using the webappname.xml. I have also added the jar in my lib folder of tomcat and still the error exists.

This is the error trace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/connectmain] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
```

Please what am I missing to get this error

Comment: How is your code using this resource, could you add that part ?

Comment: I am using it during registeration

Answer (score 0):

your xml file is not the location of this error.  You need to download jdbc drivers for your database to be able to connect to it.

Also,  I don't think your java file is the issue, but then again I don't know everything about your workspace and haven't seen a stack trace that looks exactly like this.  But your problem could also be in the method call to the database in the java file where it calls DriverManager.getConnection([url of db], [username], [password]);

Comment: Another thing that you may have missed is, Right click on your project > properties > java build path > librariers > make sure the jdbc jar is added.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should download mysql-connector-java.x.x.xx and try it.
it depends on mysql version